# Как сделать так, чтобы код js автоматически пересчитывал высоту элемента без обновления страницы?

Tags: javascript

Такая ситуация: у меня есть абсолютно спозиционированный элемент, у которого свойство top задается с помощью js. Свойство top высчитывается исходя из высоты другого элемента. Как сделать так, чтобы js автоматически пересчитывал высоту элемента при изменении ширины экрана через консоль разработчика . чтобы не приходилось обновлять страницу. (нужно на нативном js) Спасибо! 
вот код :

```
elem = document.querySelector('.header');
 var needed_height = elem.clientHeight; 
 document.querySelector(".page-search").style.top = needed_height+'px';
```

Comment: `addEventListener(“resize”, e => upd())`;

Comment: @Katya удалось разобраться и применить отслеживание resize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном примере я сделал функцию `start`, которая берёт у `.elem2` значение css-свойства `height` с пикселями при помощи [getComputedStyle](https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes#vychislennye-stili-getcomputedstyle). Если я в программе захочу как-то работать с этим значениям, то мне нужно убрать приставку `'px'` и преобразоваться эту строку в число. Я с помощью [`.slice`](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#slice)(не splice) возвращаю строку без последних двух значений `'px'` и преобразую в число с помощью [`Number`](https://learn.javascript.ru/number). А при задании свойства `height` первому элементу мы должны добавить приставку `'px'`

Также я сделал два [обработчика события](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events) - при полной загрузке страницы [`load`](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded) срабатывает функция `start`, а также при ресайзе `resize`

```js
let elem1 = document.querySelector('.elem1');
let elem2 = document.querySelector('.elem2');

function start() {
 let hElem2 = window.getComputedStyle(elem2, false).height;
 hElem2 = Number(hElem2.slice(0, hElem2.length-2));
 elem1.style.height = hElem2 + 'px';
}

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
 start();
});

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 start();
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700&display=swap');

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.elem1 {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
}

.elem2 {
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem1"></div>
<div class="elem2">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Также второй пример:
Можно не брать css-свойство, а узнать высоту элемента через [`elem.offsetHeight`](https://learn.javascript.ru/size-and-scroll) и получить значение числом, без приставки `px`. При задании css-стиля `height` мы должны добавить к этому числу приставку `'px'`

```js
let elem1 = document.querySelector('.elem1');
let elem2 = document.querySelector('.elem2');

function start() {
 let hElem2 = elem2.offsetHeight
 elem1.style.height = hElem2 + 'px';
}

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
 start();
});

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 start();
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700&display=swap');

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.elem1 {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
}

.elem2 {
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem1"></div>
<div class="elem2">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```